# How do I change an variable of a class through the parameter of a method?

Tags: python

basically I have a python class that has a variable which is initialized as `None`. I assumed that through the parameters of a method I could overwrite them. However, no matter what value I set in the parameters of that method, the variable stays None.

Now the class and the method are a lot more code, but I will reduce it to the relevant parts. However it will probably not run that way.

```
self.t = None
self.real_time_fading = True

def learn_one(self, x, t=None, sample_weight=None):
        
        # check if realtime fading is on or not. specify current time accordingly
        if self.real_time_fading:
            self.t = t
        else:
            self.t = self.n
```

The variable `t` is a time variable. When I call the method and put something for `t` like
`learn_one(x, t = 10)`, `t` still stays `None`. What is the reason for this?

**EDIT:** here is the code where I call the method

```
from river import compose
from river import feature_extraction
from river import metrics
from river import cluster
from river import stream
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

#print(stopwords.words('english'))

excluded_words = stopwords.words('english')

metric = metrics.AdjustedRand()

model = compose.Pipeline(
    feature_extraction.BagOfWords(lowercase=True, ngram_range=(1, 2), stop_words=excluded_words),
    cluster.TextClust(real_time_fading=True, fading_factor=0.0001, tgap=100, auto_r=True,
    radius=0.9)
    )

data = stream.iter_csv('tweets.csv')

i = 0

for x,_ in data:
    if i < 2000:
        prediction = model.learn_one(x['tweet'], t=x['timestamp'])
        i += 1
    else:
        break

clusters = model['TextClust'].showclusters(topn=10, num=10, type="micro")
print(clusters)
```

And the class where the issue is occurring is [TextClust.py](https://github.com/online-ml/river/blob/main/river/cluster/textclust.py)

Comment: Can u pls post the code where you’re calling the method and the output that you get?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class (static) variables and methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/class-static-variables-and-methods)

Comment: I added them method call as well as the class

Comment: Take a look at [mcve]. For example, can you replace the whole `for` loop with just `model.learn_one('hi', t=5)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`model` is a `Pipeline`, not a `TextClust`. `Pipeline.learn_one` is defined [here](https://github.com/online-ml/river/blob/487341b55ba816349ca963acf0d09fbb9d86a668/river/compose/pipeline.py):

```py
def learn_one(self, x: dict, y=None, **params):
```

so `t` goes into `params` which appears unused.